# Stating a grammar formally as a 4 tuple

Tags: grammar

Got this interview q, that I know is easy but I can't seem to get.

> State the following grammar formally as a 4-tuple. (Assume the terminal alphabet is the set of lowercase letters the appear in productions, the nonterminal alphabet is the set of uppercase letters that appear in productions and the start symbol is S.)
>   S -> *abS*|*X*
>   X -> *baX*|epsilon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grammar G is defined as a four-tuple (N, S, E, P) where:

- N is a finite set of nonterminal symbols
- S, an element of N, is the start symbol
- E is a finite set of terminal symbols
- N and E are disjoint
- P is a set of production, or ordered pairs over (N + E)* x (N + E)*

There is a derivation of string w in grammar G if there is a sequence w[1], w[2], ..., w[n] of productions in P such that:

1. w[1] = S
2. For each 1 <= i < n: w[i] = xyz, w[i+1] = xy'z and (y, y') is a production in P
3. w[n] = w is a string of terminal symbols.

The set of all strings w which have a derivation in G is called the language of G, L(G).

Now, for your grammar:

- Nonterminal symbols: S, X
- Start symbol: S
- Terminal symbols: a, b
- Productions: (S, abS), (S, X), (X, baX), (X, epsilon)